# MySQL count rows in one table based on dates in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count rows in a table `events` where a date in column `EventDate` occurs between two dates given in another table `customers`.

CUSTOMERS

```
ID  EventFrom   EventTo
--  ----------  -----------
1   2011-01-01  2012-01-01
2   2012-12-10  2013-12-10
3   2010-05-01  2011-05-01
4   2011-01-01  2012-01-01
5   2012-07-30  2013-07-30
6   2011-06-21  2012-06-21
7   2011-06-22  2012-06-22
8   2010-02-19  2011-02-19
```

EVENTS

```
ID  EventDate
--  ----------
2   1999-01-01
2   2012-12-12
2   2012-12-13
3   1900-01-12
4   2011-02-10
4   2011-02-11
4   2011-02-12
```

RESULT

```
ID  EventFrom   EventTo      Events
--  ----------  -----------  ------
1   2011-01-01  2012-01-01   0
2   2012-12-10  2013-12-10   2
3   2010-05-01  2011-05-01   0
4   2011-01-01  2012-01-01   3
5   2012-07-30  2013-07-30   0
6   2011-06-21  2012-06-21   0
7   2011-06-22  2012-06-22   0
8   2010-02-19  2011-02-19   0
```

ID 2 appears twice in `events`, but the first date does not lie between `EventTo` and `EventFrom` so it shouldn't be counted. ID 4 appears three times in `events` and all are within the correct range.

I can do it, but I end up with a nested join that is very slow.

```
SELECT customers.ID
, customers.EventFrom
, customers.EventTo
, IFNULL(e.Events, 0) AS 'Events'
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT events.ID, COUNT(events.ID) AS 'Events'
    FROM events
    INNER JOIN customers ON customers.ID = events.ID
        AND events.EventDate BETWEEN customers.EventFrom AND customers.EventTo
    GROUP BY events.ID
) e ON e.ID = customers.ID
```

I've set `EventDate` as the index in `events`. I tried setting `EventFrom` and `EventTo` as indexes too, but it didn't make a whole lot of difference. And this query is part of a larger query, so I had the indexes set up for the main part.

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT customers.ID
, customers.EventFrom
, customers.EventTo
, SUM(IF(events.EventDate BETWEEN customers.EventFrom AND customers.EventTo), 1, 0) AS 'Events'
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN events ON events.ID = customers.ID
```

Which is also incredibly slow. `customers` has about 1.5 million rows but still the query seems to take unreasonably long time. Is there better way of structuring this?

Comment: An idea: use inner join instead of left join for the counting and then use another query to add the zeroes to the result set if you really need them (perhaps you don't?). And you don't seem to actually be counting the events anywhere in your query, contrary to your claim in the first sentence.

Comment: Is COUNT(events.ID) not counting the events? I don't necessarily need the zeros, just that this is a subset of a bigger query and I want all the rows in `customers` to be returned for other purposes.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the count in the inner query, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3819/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
    (`ID` varchar(2), `EventFrom` varchar(10), `EventTo` varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
    (`ID`, `EventFrom`, `EventTo`)
VALUES
    ('1', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01'),
    ('2', '2012-12-10', '2013-12-10'),
    ('3', '2010-05-01', '2011-05-01'),
    ('4', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01'),
    ('5', '2012-07-30', '2013-07-30'),
    ('6', '2011-06-21', '2012-06-21'),
    ('7', '2011-06-22', '2012-06-22'),
    ('8', '2010-02-19', '2011-02-19')
;

CREATE TABLE EVENTS
    (`ID` int, `EventDate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO EVENTS
    (`ID`, `EventDate`)
VALUES
    (2, '1999-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2012-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2012-12-13 00:00:00'),
    (3, '1900-01-12 00:00:00'),
    (4, '2011-02-10 00:00:00'),
    (4, '2011-02-11 00:00:00'),
    (4, '2011-02-12 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.EventFrom, c.EventTo, COUNT(e.ID)
FROM CUSTOMERS c
LEFT JOIN EVENTS e ON e.ID = c.ID AND 
                      e.EventDate BETWEEN c.EventFrom AND c.EventTo
GROUP BY c.Id, c.EventFrom, c.EventTo
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3819/2/0)**:

```
| ID |  EVENTFROM |    EVENTTO | COUNT(E.ID) |
|----|------------|------------|-------------|
|  1 | 2011-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |           0 |
|  2 | 2012-12-10 | 2013-12-10 |           2 |
|  3 | 2010-05-01 | 2011-05-01 |           0 |
|  4 | 2011-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |           3 |
|  5 | 2012-07-30 | 2013-07-30 |           0 |
|  6 | 2011-06-21 | 2012-06-21 |           0 |
|  7 | 2011-06-22 | 2012-06-22 |           0 |
|  8 | 2010-02-19 | 2011-02-19 |           0 |
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much better than what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

User `left join`.  Put the date condition in the `on` clause.  Then count the matches in the table using `count(e.ID)` (which counts non-NULL values):

```
SELECT c.ID, c.EventFrom, c.EventTo,
       COUNT(e.ID) as "Events"
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     events e
     ON e.ID = c.ID and
        e.EventDate BETWEEN c.EventFrom AND c.EventTo
GROUP BY c.ID, c.EventFrom, c.EventTo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do

```
select 
  c.Id, 
  c.EventFrom,
  c.EventTo
  COUNT(e.ID)
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN events e on e.ID = c.ID and e.EvenDate BETWEEN c.EventFrom and c.EventTo
GROUP BY c.Id, c.EventFrom, c.EventTo
```